# Are these signs that my computer is being monitored or hacked?

Tags: router, isp, internet-security

I'm using this ACTalk.exe for work. It's an online classroom. Several months ago, whenever I look at Windows Performance Monitor, I can see ACTalk.exe connecting to several IP address which I think is normal while using ISP-Main (my main ISP) and I don't see any "delay" of more than 5ms.

Recently, still with ISP-Main, the ACTalk software is telling me that my "delay" is 236ms to 250ms. So I decided to take a look at the Performance Monitor again and I see that 2 ACTalk.exe is connecting to "ec.....compute-1.amazonaws.com"(kindly see screenshot uploaded). However, if I use a backup, ISP-Bak (backup ISP), there are no ACTalk.exe connecting to the "ec.....compute-1.amazonaws.com" and my "delay" is just around 70ms to 80ms.

Another weird thing is, if I use ISP-Main and do a speed test on www.speedtest.net, my "ping" is 4ms but my "delay" on ACTalk.exe is 236ms to 250ms (sometimes higher). But if I use ISP-Bak, www.speedtest.net will register 70ms to 80ms and ACTalk.exe will have a matching "delay" of 70 to 80ms. Whereas several months ago, ACTalk.exe will register a "delay" of 4ms matching that of speedtest.net.

[performance monitor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdoLv.jpg)

So my questions are:

1. Is my computer being hacked or monitored? If so, how can I deal with it?
2. Why is "ec.....compute-1.amazonaws.com" showing if I use ISP-Main while it doesn't appear when I'm using ISP-Bak?
3. Why would companies used amazonaws.com? Is it to spy on people or is it just to let users experience higher "delay or ping"?
4. In the screenshots that I uploaded, one of the ACTalk.exe has an address of 192.168.15.15. My local IP from the router starts at 192.168.15.1, so is it normal for one of the ACTalk.exe to have that IP?

Any information and enlightenment will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Complain to your ISP and demand they undo whatever they did.

Answer (score 4):

> Is my computer being hacked or monitored? If so, how can I deal with it?

No, at least not by judging by the information you've provided.

> Why is "ec.....compute-1.amazonaws.com" showing if I use ISP-Main while it doesn't appear when I'm using ISP-Bak?

It's hard to say. Probably because their infrastructure decides that this host will provide best experience.

> Why would companies used amazonaws.com? Is it to spy on people or is it just to let users experience higher "delay or ping"?

Why would a company intentionally increase someone's delays? They want you to use their services, after all.

Amazon AWS is a major cloud platform. It provides scalable computational resources. In layman's terms, they sell servers in various locations, but as soon as you don't need some of them, you can cancel your reservation and don't have to pay for them.

Companies use cloud solutions because they can easily scale up (increase number of servers when needed), scale down (decrease number of servers when not needed), they don't have to maintain hardware themselves, they don't have to worry about redundancy (backup hardware in case something fails) and **they can easily get machines in different locations to decrease latency**.

> In the screenshots that I uploaded, one of the ACTalk.exe has an address of 192.168.15.15. My local IP from the router starts at 192.168.15.1, so is it normal for one of the ACTalk.exe to have that IP?

Programs don't have IPs, network adapters do. It's either IP assigned to your computer (strictly speaking a network adapter in your computer) and the process is talking to another process on your computer or it's communicating with another machine on your network which has this IP.

Comment: Good answer. Its worth explicitly pointing out that latency is also a function of distance so its possible the AWS system being used is just far away geographically when being used through one ISP (but maybe hitting a closer node when using another ISP).

Comment: Thank you guys for the response. I'm guessing the problem is with ACTalk. I have been using ISP-Main with it for 2 years already and it never connects to AWS because the delay from speedtest.net & ACTalk are identical. However, this month (Sept), I noticed the software is displaying a delay of 236-250ms while on speedtest.net it is still consistently 4-5ms and that's the reason I decide to check Performance monitor and I saw Amazon AWS. Surfing some image intensive site is slow if the ACTALK is running. If I use ISP-Bak, it never connects to AWS ever and the delay for both are identical.